# Find all elements in list A which are in list B

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

I have the quadratic solution for the problem as below:

```
A = [12, 45, 23, 50, 87, 57]
B = [32, 10, 12, 57, 34, 99]

for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(B)):
         if A[i] == B[j]:
               print(A[i])
```

This is of course `O(N^2)`.

Another solution I thought about is sorting list `B` which is `O(n*log(n))` then binary search into `B`is `O(log(n))`, and then doing that `N` times for all items in `A`.  So that's a worst case complexity of `O(2*n*log(n)))` but w can drop the `2` since it's a constant and we have `O(n*log(n))`.

Is that correct?  Is there a way to improve that even further?

Comment: Set intersections are O(N).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am less interested in the python way of doing it; i.e. just creating a `set` using builtins and doing a union.  I am more interested in the explanation of that algorithm.

Comment: `set` uses a hash table, so membership tests are O(1). Creating an intersection is then just a question of looping over one set (O(N)) and testing each value against the other set (O(N) times O(1)).